# Mount an image created from ddrescue

Tags: live-usb, data-recovery

I know this question has been asked before, but following those answers does not seem to work for me.

I have created an image of a USB stick this is on my laptop harddrive.  How do I mount this image?

The command I used to create the image was:

ddrescue --no-split /dev/sdb usb_recovered usb_recovery_log

What am I supposed to do next?  Mount it?  Fix it then mount it?  Mount it then fix it?  And how?

**UPDATE:**

What I want to recover are the files in the image.  How? I don't know as I have tried testdisk and it can't find partitions, and I have tried fdisk and it can't find a partition table in the image either.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

To recover data from a carved image of a damaged drive we usually simply load this image to our recovery software.

For [Testdisk/Photorec](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk) [image: Install testdisk] we simply issue the following command

```
testdisk image.dd  # to recover partitions
photorec image.dd  # to recover single files
```

Please consult the very nice tutorials from CG Security on further options and steps to take:

- [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)
- [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step)

Note that you will not be able to recover filenames, permissions and directories from running PhotoRec. It will just give you random numbered files, but with an appropriate extension.

Comment: Just tried testdisk, and it found no partitions at all.  Trying photorec now.

Comment: Just finished photorec and it recovered 0 files from the usb image created using ddrescue.

Comment: @oshirowanen: you should then also try with another recovery soft. If the drive was encrypted or completely overwritten you will not be able to recover anything. That's the price we pay for security.